# mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, pero no encuentro el fallo

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy conectando a una BBDD MySQL con PHP, y estoy realizando una consulta. Me conecto a la BBDD, pero a la hora de ejecutar la consulta, me da error y no encuentro el fallo. Me da el siguiente error: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters. Este es el código:

```
$query="SELECT * WHERE IdPedido='4242-C'";
      $prueba=mysqli_query($query);
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en que no le especificas a que tabla se debe dirigir: `FROM tabla`:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE IdPedido='4242-C'";
$prueba=mysqli_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como se comenta en la documentación de PHP [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php):

Necesitas pasar dos parámetros, el primero la conexión a la BD o el enlace y el segundo la consulta, de la siguiente forma (por ejemplo):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "usuario", "password", "BD");
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Mmm ¿por qué eliminar la otra respuesta y publicar una parecida nueva?